# How do I add an onSelect functionality to a django-tables2 templateColumn dropdown list?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-tables2

```
state_template = """
<select id="state_value">
<option{% if record.action_state = 'Planned' %} selected {% endif %}>Planned
<option{% if record.action_state = 'In_Progress' %} selected {% endif %}>In Progress
<option{% if record.action_state = 'Abandoned' %} selected {% endif %}>Abandoned
<option{% if record.action_state = 'Completed' %} selected {% endif %}>Completed
</select>
"""

class PlannedActionTable(tables.Table):
    action_state = tables.TemplateColumn(state_template, verbose_name="State")
```

I need to be able to do database change upon a selection or change in the dropdown list. is there a way to do this? I tried to make a form class, but I'm not sure about how to add it to the TemplateColumn.

Comment: You will need to write some javascript which ajax posts back to the server to update the database. You really shouldn't do all that in the `TemplateColumn`. That should be in an external js file. Of course you will need to create another view to handle the ajax request. There is a lot that needs to be done to cover right here.

Comment: So even if I make a .js file, how am I supposed to add that as a drop down to a django-tables2 table?

Comment: That template column should work. Looks like you're missing a closing `</select>` though. Also, unless you have variables in your template, the value you are checking for in the if statements should be surrounded with quotes. For example: `{% if record.action_state = 'Planned' %}`

Comment: Thanks for the "</select>" heads up. I added it now. As of the quotes, it's working fine without the quotes for some reason. But I added them too. Still working on some way to do the AJAX to do stuff on onchange event.